# Manually attach Django UUIDField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, uuid

So, maybe dumb question but still I'm running into problems. I am using Python + Django (3.1.1) and DRF

I have an `id` field defined as:

```
id = UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
```

But I have a use case where someone wants to generate uuid4 on their side and use it in stead of "default" auto-generated one. I am not sure why the UUIDField does not allow manually adding it, and if I can bypass that

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class YourModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
         primary_key = True,
         default = uuid.uuid4,
         editable = True)
```